# Javascript unexpected identifier with global variable

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

I had this code on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeFinal = 3;
    function timeZone(timeBegin,timeEnd) {
        var tz = new Date();
        tz = tz.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
        timeBegin = timeBegin - tz;
        if (timeBegin <= -1) {
            timeBegin = 24 - timeBegin;
        }
        else {
        }   
        timeFinal = timeBegin + ":" timeEnd;
    }

    function FileModifDate() {
        var dateModif = document.lastModified;
        var startTimeModif = dateModif.indexOf(":") - 2;
        var time = dateModif.substring(startTimeModif, dateModif.length - 3);
        var timeBegin = time.substring(0, 1);
        var timeEnd = time.substring(3, 4);
        var date = dateModif.substring(0, 6);
        date = date.substring(3, 4) + "/" + date.substring(0, 1) + "/" + date.substring(8, 9);
        timeZone(timeBegin,timeEnd);
        dateModif = timeFinal + " " + date;
        document.getElementById('ModifDate').innerHTMl = dateModif;

    }
</script>
```

But for some reason an error happens. It says Unexpected Identifier in the line 21:

```
    timeFinal = timeBegin + ":" timeEnd;
```

**Can someone tell me what is wrong?**

Comment: You're missing a `+`, look closely...

Comment: Read that line closely and you should notice something missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
timeFinal = timeBegin + ":" + timeEnd;
```

----------------------------------------------^ you missed + here

fixed the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HFzSP/)